# Keeping SFTP tidy

Tags: marketing-cloud, ftp

Is there a nice way to periodically delete a bunch of files from the SFTP server?
Ideally I'd have a script run weekly that deletes everything older than 2 hours to stop the location filling up too much.

Any ideas would be awesome

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Import and Export folders files will be purged automatically [per the documentation](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/resources/enhanced_ftp_guide/):

> Files are removed from the FTP site after 21 days.

While I like clean folders, there's no point to cleaning them up since there are no file or storage limitations.

I expect as the Marketing Cloud becomes more like Salesforce proper, that eventually limitations will be added -- along with some way to manage them.